# How to adjust text to fit incontainer without overflow:auto

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to adjust text  to fit in container without overflow:auto... after many googling I found there is many plugin who deal with this problem but they **reduce text size**... I don't want that thing.. if Text width is large(e.g. any Url). remaining part of word  should go in next line

Comment: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap/comment-page-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using css rule `word-wrap: break-word;` with an `overflow: hidden;` to avoid scrollbars.

Also the width of the container should be set.